# c# Return http content with a stream (bytes) in the HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I am trying to return a stream (byte array actually) in a http response.
My first approach is

```
public async HttpResponseMessage GetBytes() {
    // get a memory stream with bytes
    using (var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
    {
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Header.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, on the client side (Postman), I didnt see the binary content in the response.content. it only has a content header content-type application/octet-stream, but the length is not correct, basically the real bytes are not there.

Then I switched to this approach.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetBytes() {
    // prepare the stream
    return new FileContentResult(stream.ToBytes(), MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
}
```

This time, it works, I can get the bytes on the client side. Why HttpResponseMessage does not work? I think if we can use StreamContent then we should be able to get the bytes from the content. What is the logic behind this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponseMessage` contains status information and request data. You must use the `Content` property in `HttpResponseMessage` to return the data

```
public async Task<HttpContent> GetBytes() {
    // get a memory stream with bytes
    using (var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
    {
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Header.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result.Content;
    }
}
```